# jspm - babel.js not found

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jspm

[image]

I am running my server with gulp, but for some reason I get a 404 for getting babel.js. This wasn't a problem before. This only started occurring once I installed a repo called space.js with jspm install.

I have babel defined as a dev dependency in my package.json, and all is configured properly in my config.js.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Seems strange that systemjs tries to load babel from jspm_packages/babel.js. I would expect something like /jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.25.js. Could you share your config.js `map` & `path` entries for `npm:` & `babel`?

Comment: getting same problem have you found any solution ?